# getting wrong output with multiple tables join in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, join, multiple-tables

Hello friends i have 5 tables like below

```
property_master --> "p_id" , "p_name" , "p_address" , "p_city" , "p_state" ,"r_id"

property_unit -->"unit_id"   , "p_id"  , "unit_name"   ,"r_id"

unit_info -->    "unit_info_id"   ,"unit_id" INTEGER,"p_id"   ,"p_bathroom"  ,"p_bedroom"  ,"p_size"  ,"p_rent"  ,"p_isrent"  ,"u_note" ,"r_id" 

tanant_master -->  "t_id"   , "t_name"  ,"t_cell_no"  ,"t_phone_no"  ,"t_mail"  ,"t_deposit"   ,"r_id"

property_assign-->  "t_assign_id"   , "unit_info_id"  ,  "t_id"  , "t_start_date"  , "t_end_date"  , "  t_rent_due_day"  , "t_lease_alert"  , "t_status"  ,"r_id"
```

and my query is as below

```
SELECT property_master.p_id AS "PID",
property_master.p_name AS "PropertyName",
property_master.p_address AS "ProepertyAddress",
property_master.p_city AS "ProepertyCity",
property_master.p_state AS "ProepertyState",
property_master.p_country AS "ProepertyCountry",

property_unit.p_id AS "PUID",
property_unit.unit_name AS "UnitName",
property_unit.unit_id AS "UnitID",

unit_info.p_id AS "UNPID",
unit_info.p_bathroom AS "UNBath",
unit_info.p_bedroom AS "UNBEd",
unit_info.p_size AS "UNSize",
unit_info.p_rent AS "UNRent",
unit_info.u_note AS "UNNOte",

tanant_master.p_id AS "TPID",
tanant_master.t_name AS "TPID",

property_assign.unit_info_id AS "UNITINFOID",
property_assign.t_id AS "UNITINFOID",
property_assign.t_start_date AS "UNITINFOID",
property_assign.t_end_date AS "UNITINFOID"

FROM property_master , property_unit , unit_info ,tanant_master ,   property_assign where property_assign.unit_info_id=unit_info.unit_info_id
```

[image]

**See above image it is getting duplicate value for all property**

i want that aasign property list and tenant list which is in proeprty _assign table and tanant_master table for all property but when i run above query it is give me wrong output any idea how can i solve it ?

Comment: share your wrong output with us

Comment: Tanim reja  : see my images i m getting above type wrong output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of my knowledge

-> If you want to get data from n tables you have go give n-1 conditions.

-> You have to maintain one common column for all tables or at least one common column for every two tables.

**EDIT** :

If you have **r_id** as common column in all 5 tables then write **where** condition as follows

If your tables are t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 then

```
"........WHERE t1.r_id=t2.r_id AND t1.r_id=t3.r_id AND t1.r_id=t4.r_id AND t1.r_id=t5.r_id";
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Nag :in my above 5 table one common fields is **r_id** which is my user register id .